# Merchant charging thief doubled price on stolen merchandise

Tags: criminal-law

I’m curious about an interaction between a merchant and a thief.

Drawing from a well-known Youtube channel, a prime example is a thief and a local gas station. The thief is shown in video footage stealing merchandise from the gas station. The thief then selects cheap items to purchase to avoid suspicion. The merchant engages in a trade for the “faux” merchandise and waits for the thief to leave the premises. At that point, the merchant leaves and confronts the thief. Let’s say for this example the thief admits to stealing the merchandise.

Does the merchant have a legal right to increase the sale price of the stolen merchandise? And what kind of legal actions does the merchant have available if the thief agrees to only pay the original price (assuming its legal for the merchant to increase the price of the stolen items in the first place)?

Comment: Is the guy also giving the thief the option to not purchase the merchandise, and return it instead?

Comment: Yes, the guy usually gives the thief the option to either return the merchandise and to obviously never come back, or he charges 2-3 times the initial amount.

Answer (score 1):

The options available to the merchant are:

Force the thief to hand over the stolen goods.

Charge the thief the value of the stolen goods. He cannot increase the price charged as revenge for the theft.

Comment: Why can't a merchant change the price of something arbitrarily at any time for almost any reason?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite:  There are laws against some instances of changing the price.  For example, bait and switch laws and false advertising laws.

Comment: @James Would this be one of those instances? The distinction is that the thief has not purchased the stolen goods, therefore the merchant surely isn’t bound contractually to offer the stolen goods at their advertised price, right?

Comment: @PaleBlueDot: I don't know.  I will say that the merchant is probably guilty of extortion if they tell the thief "Pay more than the actual price or I call the police".

Comment: That’s why I said almost any reason. Some places have laws about price gouging in a disaster.